# Windows 10 WPF will not autostart on system reboot when requestedExecutionLevel set to "requireAdministrator"

Tags: wpf, uac

Windows 10 WPF will not autostart on system reboot when requestedExecutionLevel set to "requireAdministrato

Answer (score 1):

you can set requestedExecutionLevel to "asInvoker"

or disable UAC

```
private bool DisableUAC()
        {
            try
            {
                string path = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System";
                string uac = "EnableLUA";
                RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(path);
                if (key != null)
                {
                    key.SetValue(uac, 0, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
                    key.Close();
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }

        private void Reboot()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown", " -r -t 0");
        }
```

Comment: If I do not want to disable UAC, because disabling this means to give a clear passage to  other unwanted apps. I want only for my app this because I know my app will not harm any thing in the system..I just want to auto start my app in boot of client PC.

Comment: try gpeidt.msc->Computer Configuration->Windows Settings->Security Settings>Local Policies->Security Options->User Account Control:Admin Approval Mode for the Build-in Administrator account->Disabled

Comment: If UAC is not disabled, the UAC dialog box will pop up when booting, which will make the user experience very poor.